# How to replace all occurences of an XML tag by its value in an SVG file

Tags: xslt, xmlstarlet

How can I replace all occurences of a given **XML tag** by its value using xslt template ?

For instance, `<tspan x="12.02" y="0">ogen</tspan>` would become `ogen`.

I can delete all  occurences using this command line:

```
xmlstarlet ed -N ns=http://www.w3.org/2000/svg -d "//ns:tspan" foo.svg
```

But I still can't find the way to replace it by its value instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider utilizing a XSL stylesheet with a template containing the necessary rules. For instance:

#### strip-tag.xsl

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
  <xsl:template match="node()[not(name()='tspan')]|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This template matches all nodes and copies them. However the [XPath](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath) expression defined in the `match` attribute, (i.e. the `[not(name()='tspan')]` part), exludes any `tspan` element nodes and their associated attribute node(s) from being copied - effectively deleting them. Child element nodes and/or text nodes of the `tspan` element will be copied, so they'll remain in the output as desired.

#### source.xml

Consider the following example `source.xml` file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<svg width="250" height="40" viewBox="0 0 250 40" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <text x="10" y="10">The <tspan x="10" y="10">quick</tspan> brown fox <tspan x="30" y="30">jumps</tspan> over the lazy dog</text> 
  <a href="https://www.example.com"><text x="100" y="100"><tspan x="50" y="50">click</tspan> me</text></a> 
</svg>
```

#### Transforming the source xml

- Running the following `xmlstarlet` command *(with the correct paths defined for the files)*:

  ```
  $ xml tr path/to/strip-tag.xsl path/to/source.xml
  ```
- Or running the following `xsltproc` command (if your system has it available):

  ```
  $ xsltproc path/to/strip-tag.xsl path/to/source.xml
  ```

will print the following to the console:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0"?>
> <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="250" height="40" viewBox="0 0 250 40" version="1.1">
>   <text x="10" y="10">The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</text>
>   <a href="https://www.example.com"><text x="100" y="100">click me</text></a>
> </svg>
> ```

**Note:** All instances of the opening and closing `tspan` tags have been removed.

#### Removing multiple

To remove multiple different named elements utilize the `and` operator in the XPath expression defined in the `match` attribute. For instance:

```xml
<!-- strip-multiple-tags.xsl-->

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
  <xsl:template match="node()[not(name()='tspan') and not(name()='a')]|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Transforming `source.xml` using this template will result in the following output:

> ```
> <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="250" height="40" viewBox="0 0 250 40" version="1.1">
>   <text x="10" y="10">The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</text>
>   <text x="100" y="100">click me</text>
> </svg>
> ```

**Note:** All instances of both `tspan` and `a` tags have been removed.

Comment: It works perfect. However, it's adding a space between the `tspan` elements. Is there some attribute to fix it ?

Comment: In the following example, I get "H y d r ogen" instead of Hydrogen: `<text transform="translate(7.75 12.38)"><tspan letter-spacing=".01em">H</tspan> <tspan letter-spacing="-.01em" x="3.97" y="0">y</tspan> <tspan x="6.73" y="0">d</tspan> <tspan letter-spacing="-.01em" x="10.12" y="0">r</tspan> <tspan x="12.02" y="0">ogen</tspan></text>` => `<text transform="translate(7.75 12.38)">H y d r ogen</tspan></text>`

Comment: Those spaces exist in the `text` tag and  not in the `tspan` tag(s).

Answer (score 0):

This snippet will do what you want:

```
<xsl:template match="tspan">
    <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
</xsl:template>
```

It finds the `tspan` elements, and discards all their content. The `xsl:value-of select="text()"` statement copies the contents of the text node only to the output.

Comment: That's why I said 'snippet'. The use of a default template was assumed.